# How to convert a MAC number to MAC string?

Tags: python

I want to convert a MAC address 00163e2fbab7 (stored as a string) to its string representation 00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How do you get the MAC address, and how is it stored in your program now? Since it wont fit in a 32-bit integer, maybe you already have it as a string that just needs to be reformated?

Comment: @Joachim: It is stored as a string.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a completely circuitous method to take advantage of an existing function that groups two hex characters at a time:

```
>>> ':'.join(s.encode('hex') for s in '00163e2fbab7'.decode('hex'))
'00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7'
```

Updated for Python 3:

```
>>> ':'.join(format(s, '02x') for s in bytes.fromhex('00163e2fbab7'))
'00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7'
```

Comment: WARNING: doesn't work if leading 0s are not in place to pad out the string

Answer (score 11):

Using the [grouper idiom](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`:

```
In [32]: addr = '00163e2fbab7'

In [33]: ':'.join(''.join(pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(addr)]*2))
Out[33]: '00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7'
```

Also possible, (and, in fact, a bit quicker):

```
In [36]: ':'.join(addr[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(addr),2))
Out[36]: '00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7'
```

Comment: The same for me: wow (itertools are great!). Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 5):

If you have a string `s` that you want to join with colons, this should do the trick.

```
':'.join([s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(0,12,2)])
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This isn't the same thing. Changing it this way would return a two-element array. You could use `''.join(s[i:i+2])`.

Comment: @Michaelior:  Not sure what you mean.  `':'.join([s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(0,12,2)])` gives the same result as `':'.join([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,12,2)])` when I run it.  String slicing does not return an array.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Of course you're right. I was thinking of something else I was playing around with which used an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you are addicted to regular expressions you could try this unpythonic approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '00163e2fbab7'
>>> ':'.join(re.findall('..', s))
'00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7'
```

Answer (score 0):

**>  Works well with python 3**

```
ap_mac = b'\xfe\xdc\xba\xab\xcd\xef'
decoded_mac = hexlify(ap_mac).decode('ascii')
formatted_mac = re.sub(r'(.{2})(?!$)', r'\1:', decoded_mac)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I adapted Josh Lee's answer above to always produce a valid MAC address:

```
def to_mac(addr: int, sep=':'):
    return sep.join('{:02x}'.format(s) for s in bytes.fromhex('{:012x}'.format(addr)))
```

#### Some examples / testing:

```
print(to_mac(0x1))
print(to_mac(0x12))
print(to_mac(0x123))
print(to_mac(0x1234))
print(to_mac(0x12345))
print(to_mac(0x123456))
print(to_mac(0x1234567))
print(to_mac(0x12345678))
print(to_mac(0x123456789))
print(to_mac(0x123456789A))
print(to_mac(0x123456789AB))
print(to_mac(0x123456789ABC, sep='-').upper())

00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:12
00:00:00:00:01:23
00:00:00:00:12:34
00:00:00:01:23:45
00:00:00:12:34:56
00:00:01:23:45:67
00:00:12:34:56:78
00:01:23:45:67:89
00:12:34:56:78:9a
01:23:45:67:89:ab
12-34-56-78-9A-BC
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = "00163e2fbab7"
mac_addr = bytes.fromhex(x).hex(":")  # 00:16:3e:2f:ba:b7
```