# Writing a 802.11 fuzzer which supports testing with WPA security enabled

Tags: wpa, fuzzing

I'm writing a fuzzer (in python) and the testing environment will be using WPA/WPA2 security. For this, I will need to either write a WPA encryption/decryption module myself or reuse WPA code from somewhere. I'm told that writing WPA code from scratch is very time consuming.

So I thought of extracting WPA code from any unix like OS's wifi device driver's source. After a lot of googling, I also came across pyrit (this may be a viable option since the fuzzer will be written in python), but I couldn't figure out how to extract and use the code as per my needs.

What will be the best place to reuse WPA code from? Or should I write the code from scratch myself?

Answer (score 0):

Found that on stackoverflow : 
[wpa-handshake with python - hashing difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018920/wpa-handshake-with-python-hashing-difficulties)

Also there is a python pypi for wifi : 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-wifi/0.5.0